# Complex if statement in visual force email template

Tags: email, email-template

I need to check two things and based on outcome display some text. The two things are that the lastModified date of an opportunity is before one date and after another

I try:

```
<apex:outputPanel rendered="{!IF((relatedTo.opportunity__r.LastModifiedDate <= NOW() - 30) && (relatedTo.opportunity___r.LastModifiedDate >= NOW() - 60, true, false))}">Stalled</apex:outputpanel>
```

I get:

```
Error: Syntax error. Missing ')'
```

But can't see where one is missing?

Any tips

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this one...

```
<apex:outputPanel rendered="{!IF((relatedTo.opportunity__r.LastModifiedDate <= NOW() - 30) && (relatedTo.opportunity___r.LastModifiedDate >= NOW() - 60), true, false)}">Stalled</apex:outputpanel>
```

It's not that one was missing per-se, its that it was in the wrong place (at the end).